# Using external JS files within Firebase CDN Script/Module Tags

Tags: javascript, firebase

Id like to use A external JavaScript script within the firebase module that I need to import....

For example:

```
  <script type="module">

  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need    
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-app.js";    
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-analytics.js";

  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use    
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries    

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration    
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional    
  const firebaseConfig = {    
    apiKey: "AIzaSyA4G1l7vDgwzXoe0RGGX327EuG_c5nsm44",    
    authDomain: "pga222.firebaseapp.com",    
    databaseURL: "https://pga222-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",    
    projectId: "pga222",    
    storageBucket: "pga222.appspot.com",    
    messagingSenderId: "233815977986",    
    appId: "1:233815977986:web:77093639624930a3ab371b",    
    measurementId: "G-QC3N2GJRC6"    
  };    

  // Initialize Firebase    
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);    
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);    

<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-javascript-file.js"></script>

</script>
```

This does not work, I presume it doesn’t work because you can't call a script inside a script.

All the scripts on my whole site are written within the Firebase module script and its getting extremely frustrating having such a mess of code to look through.

It would be much easier if I could seperate it all into chunks with external script files like you can normally do when not using Firebase.

Is there any way around this - Without using Webpack ect?
Or is that exactly what Webpack is for?

Answer (score 0):

the syntax you are using is not valid

why don't you package firebase config into a file and import it like this:

`firebase.js`:

```js
 // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need    
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-app.js";    
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-analytics.js";

  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use    
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries    

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration    
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional    
  const firebaseConfig = {    
    apiKey: "AIzaSyA4G1l7vDgwzXoe0RGGX327EuG_c5nsm44",    
    authDomain: "pga222.firebaseapp.com",    
    databaseURL: "https://pga222-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",    
    projectId: "pga222",    
    storageBucket: "pga222.appspot.com",    
    messagingSenderId: "233815977986",    
    appId: "1:233815977986:web:77093639624930a3ab371b",    
    measurementId: "G-QC3N2GJRC6"    
  };    

  // Initialize Firebase    
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);    
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);  

export { app, analytics }
```

```html
<script type="module">
import { app, analytis } from "./firebase.js"

// content file path-to-javascript-file.js
</script>
```

Comment: I dont understand how that is any different to the example I gave

Comment: learn about `modularization` in javascript